# Reusing choice definition in swagger generation with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have a Django (Django Rest Framework) webservice that uses `drf-yasg` to generate a `swagger.json` file. In the model, I have a couple of enums/choicefields that are used in more than one place. By default, `drf-yasg` defines the field inline for each occurrance:

```
Choices = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=['a', 'b', 'c'])

class SomeObject(serializers.Serializer):
    field_1 = Choices
    field_2 = Choices
```

Produces the following definitions in the swagger file:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "SomeObject": {
      "required": [ "field_1", "field_2" ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field_1": {
          "title": "Field 1",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        },
        "field_2": {
          "title": "Field 1",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a slight problem, since it makes client-codegen tools generate each enum as its own type, instead of reusing the definition. So instead I would like to create a swaggerfile like so:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "Choices": {
      "title": "Field 1",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
    },
    "SomeObject": {
      "required": [ "field_1", "field_2" ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field_1": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Choices"
        },
        "field_2": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Choices"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to enable this behaviour within the Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody sees this and needs some pointers. I ended up implementing this as follows:

Create a subclass of `ChoiceField` that is used to signal that the enum should be implemented as a reference, along with some other checks. The check for `str` is to ensure that the serialization knows how to handle the values:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from enum import Enum

class ReferenceEnumField(serializers.ChoiceField):
  def __init__(self, enum_type, **kwargs):
    if not issubclass(enum_type, str):
      raise TypeError("enum_type should inherit from str in order to be json-serializable.")
    if not issubclass(enum_type, Enum):
      raise TypeError("enum_type should be an Enum")
    self.enum_name = enum_type.__name__
    super().__init__(choices=[enum.name for enum in enum_type], **kwargs)
```

Then there is the inspector that can be added to the decorator as follows:

```
from drf_yasg.inspectors.base import NotHandled
from drf_yasg.inspectors.field import ReferencingSerializerInspector
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.errors import SwaggerGenerationError

from .ReferenceEnumfield import ReferenceEnumField

class EnumAsReferenceInspector(ReferencingSerializerInspector):
  accepting_objects = True

  @classmethod
  def set_accepting_objects(cls, value):
    cls.accepting_objects = value

  def field_to_swagger_object(self, field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs):
    SwaggerType, ChildSwaggerType = self._get_partial_types(field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs)


    if EnumAsReferenceInspector.accepting_objects and isinstance(field, ReferenceEnumField):
      try:
        # Avoid infinite recursion by setting the class to not accept objects to serialize.
        EnumAsReferenceInspector.set_accepting_objects(False)
        if swagger_object_type != openapi.Schema:
          raise SwaggerGenerationError("cannot instantiate nested serializer as " + swagger_object_type.__name__)

        ref_name = field.enum_name

        def make_schema_definition(enum=field):
          return self.probe_field_inspectors(enum, ChildSwaggerType, use_references)
        if not ref_name or not use_references:
          return make_schema_definition()

        definitions = self.components.with_scope(openapi.SCHEMA_DEFINITIONS)
        actual_schema = definitions.setdefault(ref_name, make_schema_definition)
        actual_schema._remove_read_only()

        return openapi.SchemaRef(definitions, ref_name)
      finally:
        EnumAsReferenceInspector.set_accepting_objects(True)

    return NotHandled
```

It's cobbled together from some other code in the library, so I'm not sure if there are lines that could be ommitted or done differently, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and fixed it with a modified version of [JAD's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034829/19465550).

There is no need to create a custom serializer (you can simply leverage DRF's ChoiceField), you only need to plug in a ReferenceSerializerInspector to your list of drfyasg field inspectors:

```
from inflection import camelize
from rest_framework import serializers
from drf_yasg.inspectors import ReferencingSerializerInspector, NotHandled
from drf_yasg.errors import SwaggerGenerationError
from drf_yasg import openapi


class EnumAsReferenceInspector(ReferencingSerializerInspector):
    accepting_objects = True

    def get_ref_name(self, serializer: serializers.ChoiceField) -> str:
        """Return the name of the reference to the enum, e.g. `EnumName` or `ModelNameEnumName`.

        Args:
            serializer (serializers.ChoiceField): The serializer field.

        Returns:
            str: The name of the reference to the enum.
        """
        ref_name: str = serializer.field_name
        try:
            parent_obj_name = serializer.parent.Meta.model._meta.object_name
            ref_name = camelize(f"{parent_obj_name}_{ref_name}")
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return ref_name

    @classmethod
    def set_accepting_objects(cls, value):
        cls.accepting_objects = value

    def field_to_swagger_object(
        self, field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs
    ):
        _, ChildSwaggerType = self._get_partial_types(
            field, swagger_object_type, use_references, **kwargs
        )

        if EnumAsReferenceInspector.accepting_objects and isinstance(
            field, serializers.ChoiceField
        ):
            try:
                # Avoid infinite recursion by setting the class to not accept objects to serialize.
                EnumAsReferenceInspector.set_accepting_objects(False)
                if swagger_object_type != openapi.Schema:
                    raise SwaggerGenerationError(
                        "cannot instantiate nested serializer as "
                        + swagger_object_type.__name__
                    )

                ref_name = self.get_ref_name(field)

                def make_schema_definition(enum=field):
                    return self.probe_field_inspectors(
                        enum, ChildSwaggerType, use_references
                    )

                if not ref_name or not use_references:
                    return make_schema_definition()

                definitions = self.components.with_scope(openapi.SCHEMA_DEFINITIONS)
                actual_schema = definitions.setdefault(ref_name, make_schema_definition)
                actual_schema._remove_read_only()

                return openapi.SchemaRef(definitions, ref_name)
            finally:
                EnumAsReferenceInspector.set_accepting_objects(True)

        return NotHandled
```